# Android - Listing of all in app Google purchaseable items for an app - Does it still not exist?

Tags: android, android-billing

I've seen this asked 2 and 3 years ago without a simple solution of how to query for all of the items in my in app purchase dashboard.  With it being 2016 is there a way to do this now.  I still don't see anything in the doc of how to query all of the product sku's that then you can get the details on.

UPDATE: so is there no way to query all of the existing listing that you have as in-app purchases or is the only way to know the list ahead of time and you can then query for their price as entered in the dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

Sad, but you have to store and query list of skus from back-end.

I cannot get what security issue google team solve by this decision.

Comment: Thanks yeah I finally figured that out as well.  What is bad is that you can't update the server without updating the client unless you store the list on your own server.

Comment: That way google pushes us to use firebase. Ideally your server should be the place to work with in-app products (some kind of web admin panel, yeah google console duplication) and synchronize with google play by [API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/).